# Python , pyinstaller with matplotlib and numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

So i need to build python .exe , but I have a problem because after building exe, it gets information about missing modules. I tried to downgrade to an older version of matplotlib, currently using matplotlib 3.2.2. However, the exe file still won't start, gives some error and shuts down automatically.

```
 missing module named org - imported by copy (optional)
missing module named _posixsubprocess - imported by subprocess (optional), multiprocessing.util (delayed)
missing module named grp - imported by shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), pathlib (delayed, optional), subprocess (optional), distutils.archive_util (optional)
missing module named pwd - imported by posixpath (delayed, conditional), shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), pathlib (delayed, conditional, optional), subprocess (optional), http.server (delayed, optional), webbrowser (delayed), netrc (delayed, conditional), getpass (delayed), distutils.util (delayed, conditional, optional), distutils.archive_util (optional)
missing module named _posixshmem - imported by multiprocessing.resource_tracker (conditional), multiprocessing.shared_memory (conditional)
missing module named multiprocessing.set_start_method - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.spawn (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.get_start_method - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.spawn (top-level)
missing module named urllib.pathname2url - imported by urllib (conditional), PyInstaller.lib.modulegraph._compat (conditional)
missing module named pep517 - imported by importlib.metadata (delayed)
missing module named posix - imported by os (conditional, optional), shutil (conditional), importlib._bootstrap_external (conditional)
missing module named resource - imported by posix (top-level), test.support (delayed, conditional, optional)
excluded module named _frozen_importlib - imported by importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), zipimport (top-level), PyInstaller.loader.pyimod02_archive (delayed)
missing module named _frozen_importlib_external - imported by importlib._bootstrap (delayed), importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), zipimport (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.get_context - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.pool (top-level), multiprocessing.managers (top-level), multiprocessing.sharedctypes (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.TimeoutError - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.pool (top-level)
missing module named _scproxy - imported by urllib.request (conditional)
missing module named termios - imported by tty (top-level), getpass (optional)
missing module named 'java.lang' - imported by platform (delayed, optional), xml.sax._exceptions (conditional)
missing module named multiprocessing.BufferTooShort - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.connection (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.AuthenticationError - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.connection (top-level)
missing module named asyncio.DefaultEventLoopPolicy - imported by asyncio (delayed, conditional), asyncio.events (delayed, conditional)
missing module named vms_lib - imported by platform (delayed, optional)
missing module named java - imported by platform (delayed)
missing module named _winreg - imported by platform (delayed, optional), pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (delayed, conditional)
missing module named readline - imported by cmd (delayed, conditional, optional), code (delayed, conditional, optional), pdb (delayed, optional)
missing module named 'org.python' - imported by pickle (optional), xml.sax (delayed, conditional), setuptools.sandbox (conditional)
missing module named 'nose.plugins' - imported by numpy.testing._private.noseclasses (top-level), numpy.testing._private.nosetester (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.integer - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.fft.helper (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.conjugate - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level)
missing module named pickle5 - imported by numpy.compat.py3k (optional)
missing module named _dummy_thread - imported by numpy.core.arrayprint (optional)
missing module named numpy.array - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level), numpy.ma.extras (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level), numpy.ctypeslib (top-level)
missing module named numpy.recarray - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level)
missing module named numpy.ndarray - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level), numpy.ma.extras (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level), numpy.ctypeslib (top-level)
missing module named numpy.dtype - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level), numpy.ctypeslib (top-level)
missing module named numpy.bool_ - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level)
missing module named numpy.expand_dims - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.iscomplexobj - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.amin - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.amax - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.histogramdd - imported by numpy (delayed), numpy.lib.twodim_base (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.ufunc - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.ones - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.hstack - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.atleast_1d - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.atleast_3d - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.shape_base (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.vstack - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.shape_base (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.linspace - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.index_tricks (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.transpose - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.function_base (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.result_type - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.float_ - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.number - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.bool_ - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.inf - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.array2string - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.signbit - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.isscalar - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.isinf - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.isnat - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.ndarray - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level), numpy.lib.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.array_repr - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.arange - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level), numpy.fft.helper (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.float32 - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.iinfo - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.twodim_base (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.sort - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.argsort - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.sign - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.isnan - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.count_nonzero - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.divide - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.swapaxes - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.matmul - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.object_ - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.asanyarray - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.intp - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.atleast_2d - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.product - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.amax - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.amin - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.moveaxis - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.geterrobj - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.errstate - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.finfo - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.isfinite - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.sum - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.fastCopyAndTranspose - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.sqrt - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.multiply - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.add - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.dot - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.Inf - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.all - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.newaxis - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.complexfloating - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.inexact - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.cdouble - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.csingle - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.double - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.single - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.intc - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.empty_like - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.empty - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level), numpy.fft.helper (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.zeros - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.asarray - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.lib.utils (top-level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level), numpy.fft.helper (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.array - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.eye - imported by numpy (delayed), numpy.core.numeric (delayed)
missing module named 'nose.util' - imported by numpy.testing._private.noseclasses (top-level)
missing module named psutil - imported by numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed, optional)
missing module named win32pdh - imported by numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed, conditional)
missing module named 'IPython.core' - imported by matplotlib.backend_bases (delayed), matplotlib.pyplot (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named IPython - imported by matplotlib.backend_bases (delayed), matplotlib.pyplot (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named __builtin__ - imported by pyparsing (conditional), pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing (conditional), setuptools._vendor.pyparsing (conditional)
missing module named ordereddict - imported by pyparsing (optional), pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing (optional), setuptools._vendor.pyparsing (optional)
missing module named dummy_threading - imported by numpy.distutils.misc_util (optional), numpy.distutils.ccompiler (optional), matplotlib.font_manager (optional), matplotlib.backends.backend_agg (optional)
runtime module named six.moves - imported by dateutil.tz.tz (top-level), dateutil.tz._factories (top-level), dateutil.tz.win (top-level), dateutil.rrule (top-level), cycler (top-level)
missing module named six.moves.zip - imported by six.moves (top-level), cycler (top-level)
missing module named six.moves.range - imported by six.moves (top-level), dateutil.rrule (top-level)
missing module named StringIO - imported by PyInstaller.lib.modulegraph._compat (conditional), PyInstaller.lib.modulegraph.zipio (conditional), six (conditional)
missing module named dateutil.tz.tzfile - imported by dateutil.tz (top-level), dateutil.zoneinfo (top-level)
missing module named olefile - imported by PIL.MicImagePlugin (top-level), PIL.FpxImagePlugin (top-level)
missing module named 'IPython.display' - imported by PIL.ImageShow (optional)
missing module named 'PySide2.QtGui' - imported by PIL.ImageQt (conditional, optional)
missing module named PySide2 - imported by PIL.ImageQt (conditional, optional)
missing module named 'PyQt5.QtGui' - imported by PIL.ImageQt (conditional, optional)
missing module named 'PySide6.QtGui' - imported by PIL.ImageQt (conditional, optional)
missing module named PySide6 - imported by PIL.ImageQt (conditional, optional)
missing module named 'PyQt6.QtGui' - imported by PIL.ImageQt (conditional, optional)
missing module named PyQt6 - imported by PIL.ImageQt (conditional, optional)
missing module named cffi - imported by win32ctypes.core (optional), PIL.Image (optional), PIL.PyAccess (optional), PIL.ImageTk (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named 'tornado.template' - imported by matplotlib.backends.backend_webagg (delayed)
missing module named 'tornado.websocket' - imported by matplotlib.backends.backend_webagg (top-level)
missing module named 'tornado.ioloop' - imported by matplotlib.backends.backend_webagg (top-level)
missing module named 'tornado.web' - imported by matplotlib.backends.backend_webagg (top-level)
missing module named tornado - imported by matplotlib.backends.backend_webagg (optional), matplotlib.backends.backend_webagg_core (top-level)
missing module named matplotlib.tri.Triangulation - imported by matplotlib.tri (top-level), matplotlib.tri.trifinder (top-level), matplotlib.tri.tritools (top-level), matplotlib.tri.triinterpolate (top-level)
missing module named matplotlib.axes.Subplot - imported by matplotlib.axes (top-level), matplotlib.pyplot (top-level)
missing module named matplotlib.axes.Axes - imported by matplotlib.axes (top-level), matplotlib.pyplot (top-level), matplotlib.legend (delayed), matplotlib.projections.geo (top-level), matplotlib.projections.polar (top-level), mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d (top-level), matplotlib.figure (top-level)
missing module named 'scipy.spatial' - imported by D:\Projekt_matma\projekt\projekt\projekt.py (top-level)
missing module named pytest - imported by matplotlib (delayed, optional)
```

I appreciate any help as I have no idea what to do with it. This is my first time generating python to exe.

Comment: What is the script / app that you use for exe creation? How do you configure it?

Comment: It looks like you are using `pyinstaller`. If so, the docs have a very helpful section called *When things go wrong*. I suggest you work through it.

Comment: I was able to establish that my failure to run the file was probably caused by:
" from scipy.spatial import convex_hull_plot_2d  "
I changed my code so that I no longer need convex_hull_plot_2d and numpy to work properly. I'm still getting messages about missing modules, although my .exe file is already starting and it looks like the application is working properly.